# Кодировка в Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublime-text

Раньше был на `Notepad++`, сейчас решил осваивать новый для меня текстовый редактор. Возник вопрос по поводу кодировки: где её задавать/изменять?
В `Notepad++` у файла была кодировка `UTF-8 (без BOM)`: открываю его в `Sublime Text` и вижу, что кириллица отображается некорректно.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

У меня в меню `File` есть пункт `Reopen With Encoding...`
Однако, я использую Mac-версию, но думаю, что и на остальных есть такая.

Comment: Спасибо. Я выбрал Cyrillic (Windows 1251).

Верно ли я выбрал?

Comment: Вы же написали, что в Notepad++ у вас была UTF-8 - её и выбирайте.

Comment: Я вот тоже только начал использовать sublime подскажите пожалуйста где я могу подсмотреть кодировку используемого файла. В notepad++ она отображается внизу рабочего окна.

Answer (score 2):

для Sublime 3

preferences -> settings User -> "default_encoding": "UTF-8 with BOM"

Answer (score 0):

Про кодировки Sublime Text 3 я расписал в пункте 1 [данного ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/513322/199934). Также помимо функции <kbd>Reopen With Encoding</kbd>, упомянутой в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/513322/199934) VioLet, мы можем и сохранять файлы в нужной нам кодировке: <kbd>File</kbd> → <kbd>Save with Encoding</kbd>. Спасибо.