# Несколько вопросов по редактору Sublime Text

Tags: вёрстка, ide, редактор, sublime-text

Поставил Sublime Text 2, пытаюсь привыкнуть.

1. Вопрос про кодировку. Во многих редакторах можно узнать кодировку файла и даже увидеть её в строке состояния (UTF-8/ANSI).

   В Sublime можно только "сохранить в кодировке.." или "открыть в кодировке.." но изначальную кодировку узнать невозможно.

   Собственно вопрос: как вывести информацию о кодировке в строку состояния. Или хотя бы добавить пункт в меню "file->encoding".
2. У меня часть файлов с php-скриптами сохранены с расширением .inc 
   Как заставить Sublime понимать их как пхп-шные? По умолчанию он принимает файл с расширением .inc как HTML файл (пишет в строке состояния "HTML")

   Вроде бы есть плагин DetectSyntax, но мне кажется это должно решаться проще, в настройках.

   > ```
   > // что-то типа:
   > // ассоциировать расширения файлов
   > "associate_extension" : "inc,tpl,wtf - php"
   > ```
3. Вопрос про закладки (Bookmarks): 
   можно ли делать нумерованные закладки (или может "именные")?

   Например, в PHP ExpertEdit - можно закладки <kbd>alt+n</kbd> и соответственно переходить по закладкам <kbd>ctrl+n</kbd>

   Сейчас в Sublime устроено так, что добраться до нужной закладки можно только перебором.

   > ```
   > //Можно было бы сделать по аналогии с поиском методов: 
   > ctrl+shit+p -> @ -> method name
   > ctrl+r -> @ -> method  name
   >
   > //а для закладок сделать так (бы):
   > ctrl+shit+p -> # -> bookmark number or name
   > ```

Соответственно, при установке закладок предлагать вводить номер или титл.

Comment: О нет, закрыватели и до вопросов по Sublime Text добрались( .

Answer (score 3):

Решение для `Sublime Text 3`:

1. <kbd>Preferences</kbd> → <kbd>Settings - User</kbd>. В открывшемся файле между `{}` добавить параметр `show_encoding` со значением `true`:

`"show_encoding": true, // Показывать в Status Bar кодировку файла`

В правом углу Status Bar появится новая кнопка, где высвечивается кодировка открытого файла:

[image: Кодировка в Status Bar]

Параметром `default_encoding` задаётся кодировка, используемая для открытия файлов с неопределённой кодировкой и сохранения новых. Значение по умолчанию — `"UTF-8"`, в большинстве случаев здесь лучше ничего не трогать.

А вот строку

```
"fallback_encoding": "Cyrillic (Windows 1251)", // Используемая кодировка, когда кодировка не определяется автоматически
```

необходимо добавить в открывающийся после <kbd>Preferences</kbd> → <kbd>Settings - User</kbd> файл сразу же после установки `Sublime Text 3`, иначе кириллические тексты отобразятся кракозябрами, да если ещё их сохранить, то обратная раскодировка [декодером](https://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/decoder/) может и не получиться.

2. Открываем любой документ с расширением `.inc` . <kbd>View</kbd> → <kbd>Syntax</kbd> → <kbd>Open all with current extention as...</kbd> → <kbd>PHP</kbd>. После этого ко всем файлам с расширением `.inc` будет применена php-подсветка.
3. Плагин [Sublime Bookmarks](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Sublime%20Bookmarks):

[image: Пример работы Sublime Bookmarks]

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

1. package control:install package  >  status bar extension
2. выбор подсветки в правом нижнем углу statusbar-а.
3. ctrl+p - переход по закладкам