# Автопреобразование в .less файлах, Sublime Text + Emmet

Tags: sublime-text, emmet

В файлах *style.less* код `cb` после нажатия <kbd>Tab</kbd> у меня трансформируется в `<cb>`, а нужно, чтобы трансформировалось в `clear:both;`.

Comment: У меня нормально, в `clear:both` преобразуется. Предположу, что Вы не выставили синтаксис: это приходится сделать вручную (как — см. [п. 2 моего ответа](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/513322/199934)), ибо по умолчанию к файлам с расширением `.less` применяется синтаксис `Plain Text`,  а не `CSS`. Спасибо.