# Отсутствует подсветка синтаксиса в sublime text windows 7

Tags: sublime-text

HTML-код выглядит вот так:

[image: html]

Пробовал менять цветовые схемы, но меняется только цвет фона, а текст остаётся таким.

Comment: А синтаксис документа пробовали менять?

Comment: Не. Буду благодарен, если подскажете как это сделать.

Comment: В правом нижнем углу нажмите на Syntax и вместо Plain Text выберите HTML

Comment: СПАСИТЕЛЬ!!! А сколько я лишних действий наделал из-за такой ерунды.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для включение подстветки синтаксиса есть как минимум 3 способа:

- В правом нижнем углу документа нажмите на "Plain Text", далее на
  "Syntax (Синтаксис)" и в появившемся списке выберите соответствующий
  вашему документу синтаксис.
- В главном меню нажмите на "View (Вид)", далее на "Syntax
  (Синтаксис)" и в появившемся списке выберите соответствующий вашему
  документу синтаксис.
- Откройте Командную панель, нажав
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> или выбрав в меню "Tools (Инструменты)" - "Command Palette (Командная панель)", введите "Set Syntax"
  и соответствующий вашему документу синтаксис, после чего нажмите <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

За дополнение спасибо VenZell.

Comment: Можно еще нажать `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `P` и набрать `set syntax HTML`, после чего жмакнуть `Enter`. Поддерживается fuzzy-поиск, т.е. неполный ввод слов. Например `sshtml` или `ssht` найдут то же самое.

Comment: Нумерованный список обычно воспринимается как пошаговая инструкция, поэтому поменял на маркированный.

Comment: Минус ответу по двум причинам. // **1.** Кружок и имя вкладки позволяют предположить, что эта вкладка у автора несохранённая. Для несохранённых вкладок, если не ошибаюсь, по умолчанию и стоит Plain Text. [**Это можно изменить**](https://toster.ru/q/335977?e=4590642#answer_item_850379). Если же воспользоваться Вашим методом — следующая несохранённая вкладка опять откроется с Plain Text.

Comment: // **2.** Для сохранённых вкладок, если пользоваться содержимым Вашего ответа, также придётся менять синтаксис каждый раз, как откроется новый файл с расширением. Как сделать, чтобы синтаксис сохранился навсегда, см. [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/513322/199934) в п.2. Спасибо.