# Как удобно работать с URL написанном на русском языке?

Tags: url, utf-8, sublime-text

Типичный URL содержащий русский текст, при вставке в любой текстовой редактор превращается в подобный нечитабельный набор кода. Пример:

> [Несколько вопросов по редактору Sublime Text](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/213387/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83-sublime-text?newreg=5667916508f04ceea36afc87d54b42a8)

Выглядит как:

> `https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/213387/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%83-sublime-text?newreg=5667916508f04ceea36afc87d54b42a8`

Работать в редакторе  с таким текстом очень сложно, а иногда необходимо писать и редактировать там много осмысленного текста.

Подскажите, есть ли какой удобный способ и инструмент "скопипастить" текст так, чтобы потом можно было работать в редакторе именно с русским текстом?
В качестве редактора я пользуюсь Sublime text, но если нужен какой другой или плагин, прошу подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ для Браузера Хром (хотя м.б. и остальные себя так ведут) и копирования ссылки из строки адреса:

1. Ставите курсор в строку с URL
2. Сдвигаетесь максимально влево (кнопкой Home)
3. Добавляете 1 пробел
4. Выделяете текст URL (Shift+End)
5. Копируете (Ctrl+C)
6. Вуаля, у вас "нормальная" ссылка , типа `https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1506892/Как-удобно-работать-с-url-написанном-на-русском-языке`

Comment: Спасибо идея в целом помогла, но добавление пробела, у меня, по крайней мере на маке, не действует. Но вот если перед https написать какие нибудь буквы, а затем скопировать, то копипаст работает как надо.