# Проблемы кодировки в ST2

Tags: кодировка, sublime-text

У меня не получается открыть НИ ОДИН ФАЙЛ через Sublime Text 2. Если открою то вижу такую картину[image: Такая картина]

Comment: На этот вопрос уже отвечали :) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/122595/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-sublime-text-2

Почему ST2, а не ST3?

Comment: А какая кодировка? Попробовал некоторые, и вижу что-то примерно
https://i.imgur.com/JqZ5l7g.png

Comment: Обычно используется UTF-8, UTF-8 (с БОМ) и Windows-1251

Comment: У меня нету 2151

Comment: Это шестнадцатеричный режим. Скорее всего вы открываете бинарный файл. Судя по обилию `cc` (команда `int3`, которой обычно заполняется пустое место между процедурами) - это какой-то исполняемый файл, его вообще бессмысленно пытаться открыть текстовым редактором.

Comment: P.S. а `c3` перед каждым блоком `cc` - это `ret` (возврат из процедуры) в машинном коде, так что это точно исполняемый файл.

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы пытаетесь открыть бинарный файл с помощью Sublime Text, он понимает что это не текстовый файл (возможно по наличию нулевых байт в файле), и отображает его в шестнадцатеричном виде. В данном случае вы похоже пытаетесь открыть исполняемый файл в текстовом редакторе - а это довольно бессмысленно.

`У меня не получается открыть НИ ОДИН ФАЙЛ через Sublime Text 2` - попробуйте открывать текстовые файлы, а не бинарные. Уверен, что все нормально откроется.